# How does Buddhist soteriology link to the first cause argument?

Tags: theology, causation, buddhism, aquinas

> Aquinas [argued](https://www.britannica.com/topic/first-cause) that the observable order of causation is not
>   self-explanatory. It can only be accounted for by the existence of a
>   first cause; this first cause, however, must not be considered simply
>   as the first in a series of continuing causes, but rather as first
>   cause in the sense of being the cause for the whole series of
>   observable causes.

So, says Aquinas, everything must have a cause, except the "first" cause, which must then be present in everything.

Is it too whacky to claim that the universality of Buddhist soteriology, as well as their denial of God and atman, is powered by an intuition that the ***end*** of a causal series is already present?

In the same way that a pitcher of water is already void before we empty it.

I'll put another, *hopefully* clearer way.

'Cause' is contained in 'effect' [everything is caused] but 'effect' is not contained in 'cause' [a causal series can be snuffed out]: if we call the root cause of our discontinuous illusions "ignorance", the cause of suffering, then wouldn't that mean it, ignorance, is already both present [samsara] and absent [nirvana] from moment to moment: that the **end** of conditioned suffering is now?

Comment: What is "Buddhist soteriology"?

Comment: Nice one! But wondering if: _"the end of a causal series is already present"_ and _"'effect' is not contained in 'cause'"_ isn't contradictory?

Comment: I would suggest that you look beyond the soteriology and study the metaphysics. Like Aquinas, Buddhists speak of an 'uncaused cause'. Samsara and Nirvana would, as you say, be present from moment to moment. I'm struggling to disentangle the question though so cannot say much more.  . .

Comment: @Geremia — Buddhist soteriology is a thing: it concerns the escape from the cycles of karma into liberation, and ultimately nirvana. It's not strictly equivalent to Christian soteriology, but there are enough parallels to make it a meaningful phrase.

Comment: Does Buddhism believe in an eternal or finite universe?

Comment: i think it's an unanswered question -- neither

Comment: Some Buddhist schools are more philosophical than others; one that lends itself to rational philosophizing is Tiantai, which has its [own Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-tiantai/). The article discusses some ideas that seem relevant to your question, especially the idea that 'every event, function or characteristic occurring in any experience anywhere is the action of all sentient and insentient beings working together'.

Comment: i've read a couple of ziporyn's books. tientai isn't especially subtle philosophy -- not more than madhyamaka or yogacara or even huayen -- but it is a subtle [mao?] interpretation of buddhism, imho